# Excel web service call on save

Tags: web-services, excel, file-upload

I have an application that uploads bulk (master) data from users. Now instead of creating forms i figured that i could download the existing data into excel and the user simply changes what they need to in Excel, and click on say 'save' or some buttom provided on theexcel worksheet, which in turn invokes a web service to load this data into the app. (we already have a web service api for this). I am assuming that when i download the excel file (from the server) to the user, the macros that are in the excel file are also now available to the user. 
Any thoughts on the approach and if this sounds ok, any suggestions on how i can modify the excel file so that when the user clicks 'save' it gets uploaded (rather that get saved on the users system). Also not sure how to invoke a WS from within Excel to do this.
thx in advance,
-anish

Comment: This is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/): [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

While some of the details you may have to investigate yourself, I've created the following library for interacting with web services that may help:

https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST

Here's a quick example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Api As New RestClient
    Api.BaseUrl = "http://.../yourapi/"

    Dim Data As New Collection
    ' Add data from sheet...

    ' Create update request to api
    Dim Request As New RestRequest
    Request.Resource = "resource/{id}"
    Request.AddUrlSegment "id", "123"
    Request.Body Data
    Request.Method = httpPUT

    ' Execute the update
    Dim Response As RestResponse
    Set Response = Api.Execute(Request)

    ' Check on what happened
    If Response.StatusCode < 400 Then
        ' Success!
    Else
        ' Uh oh, check on the error
        MsgBox Response.Content
    End If
End Sub
```